# Unexpected open curly brace?

Tags: jquery

I'm really confused by this, I've read through the code plenty of times, but I can't work out why this is wrong. I've reduced it down to it's most simple form (`...`s replaced with `alert();`s) and I still get this error:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$(".foo").hover(function() {
   ...
 },function() {
   ...
});

${"#bar"}.click(function() {    <---- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
  ...
});


});
```

Comment: ${"#bar"}.click
-^ that must be a () no?

Comment: There is a `{` instead of the `(`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
${"#bar"}
```

with

```
$("#bar")
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that be:

```
$("#bar").click(function() {
```

you have braces instead of parenthesis around #bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

$(document).ready(function() {


$(".foo").hover(function() {
   ...
 },function() {
   ...

});

$("#bar").click(function() {    <---- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
  ...
});


});
```